# How to avoid retain cycle in CEF

Tags: chromium-embedded

I want to integrate CEF3 into my application, it says that the CefRefPtr is a smart pointer. I test it with a retain cycle, the resources cannot be released either. I wander if there is a weak pointer like obj-c and boost do ? Or is there another way to avoid retain cycle in CEF3

Comment: You can release smart pointers with the Release() method. If you don't want smart pointers, CEF provides C API, but you still need to implement a way for releasing resources.

Comment: Thanks. I do want smart pointers, I just wanna to figure out the difference between smart pointers in CEF and ARC in Obj-c. Since in Objc with ARC enabled, you should take care of retain cycle, I want to know what is the best way to deal with retain cycle in CEF.

Comment: CEF uses smart reference counted pointers, so your question might as well be in general regarding retain cycle in smart reference counted pointers, try google.

Comment: Btw. the best chance for getting answers to CEF related questions are on the CEF Support Forum - http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=6

Comment: @CzarekTomczak There are still significant leaks happening with CEF3 1916 build.